# (Resolved) What is the correct way to pass a Ruby ROR variable to a Javascript widget script?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in programming and I can't find the right syntax for passing a ruby on rails variable to a JS widget script.

I have a widget define inside a ROR partial. I have to implement lots of widgets in my app and
considering that I do not want as many partials as widgets are and that the only variable within the widget script is the widget_id I should:

Have a partial that interpolates the variable widget_id in the script.
Render the partial from wherever it is needed passing the variable widget_id
`<%= render "freshdesk_widget", widget_id: 60000003588 %>`

**Widget working --->**

```
<%= render "admin/users/partials/freshdesk_widget"%>
```

```
<script>
        window.fwSettings={
        'widget_id': 60000003588

        };
        !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/60000003588.js" async defer></script>
```

**Attemp-->**

```
<%= render "freshdesk_widget", widget_id: 60000003588 %>
```

```
<script>
        window.fwSettings={
        'widget_id': @widget_id

        };
        !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/<%= @widget_id %>.js" async defer></script>
```

***SOLUTION ---> Because I set the variable in a ruby template this is the right syntax!***

```
<script>
        window.fwSettings={
        'widget_id': <%= widget_id %>
        };
        !function(){if("function"!=typeof window.FreshworksWidget){var n=function(){n.q.push(arguments)};n.q=[],window.FreshworksWidget=n}}()
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/<%= widget_id %>.js' async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the widget id in a dataset attribute.

```
# view
<div id="widget" data-widgetid="<%= widget_id %>">
</div>

# js
let widgetId = document.querySelector("#widget").datatset["widgetid"]
```